# Complex regular expression getting less than expected

Tags: python, regex, text-mining

I am trying to fiddle with a regex in *Python 2.7* in order to catch numbered footnotes in a text. My text as converted from PDF looks like:

```
test_str = u"""
7. On 6 March 2013, the Appeals Chamber filed the Decision on Victim 
Participation, in which it decided that the victims “may, through their legal 

1
 The full citation, including the ICC registration reference of all designations and abbreviations used in 
this judgment are included in Annex 1. 
2
 A more detailed procedural history is set out in Annex 2 of this judgment. 
ICC-01/04-02/12-271-Corr  07-04-2015  7/117  EK  A

 8/117 
representatives, participate in the present appeal proceedings for the purpose of 
presenting their views and concerns in respect of their personal interests in the issues 
on appeal”.3

8. On 19 March 2013, the Prosecutor filed, confidentially, ex parte, available to the 
Prosecutor and Mr Ngudjolo only, the Document in Support of the Appeal. The 
Prosecutor filed a confidential redacted version of the Document in Support of the 
Appeal on 22 March 2013, and a public redacted version of the Document in Support 
of the Appeal on 3 April 2013. In the redacted version of the Document in Support of 
the Appeal, the Prosecutor’s entire third ground of appeal was redacted. 

"""
```

Please note that *numbered paragraphs* that are the regular content of my text, are **prefixed with a number and dot (like '5.')**.
 Ideally, I 'd like to get something like:

```
[(1,"The full citation, including the ICC registration reference of all designations and abbreviations used in 
this judgment are included in Annex 1. "), (2, "A more detailed procedural history is set out in Annex 2 of this judgment."
```

My Python code for getting the footnotes is:

```
regex = ur"""
(\r?\n)(?P<num>\d+)(?!\.) #first line
(?P<text>(?:\s(.|\r?\n)+?\s?(?:\n\n|\Z))) #following lines
"""
result = re.findall(regex, test_str, re.U|re.VERBOSE | re.X |re.MULTILINE)
```

which gives me:

```
[(u'\n', u'1', u'\n The full citation, including the ICC registration reference of all designations and abbreviations used in \nthis judgment are included in Annex 1. \n\n', u'.')]
```

i.e. only the *first footnote*, while I need both off course

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: where should the 2nd footnote get ended? And what is the expected content of the 3rd footnote?

Comment: The 2nd footnote should end at `"...Annex 2 of this judgment. "` and there is no 3rd footnote. It was a pdf2txt error. I have corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this regex: `(^\d+(?!\.).*?)(?=^\s*\d)` works as you describe.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/n59wZV/3/)

Python demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> print ''.join(re.findall(r'(^\d+(?!\.).*?)(?=^\s*\d)', test_str, flags=re.M|re.S))
1
 The full citation, including the ICC registration reference of all designations and abbreviations used in 
this judgment are included in Annex 1. 
2
 A more detailed procedural history is set out in Annex 2 of this judgment. 
ICC-01/04-02/12-271-Corr  07-04-2015  7/117  EK  A
```

If you want to capture the footnote number separate from the text:

```
>>> re.findall(r'^(\d+)((?!\.).*?)(?=\s*^\d)', test_str, flags=re.M|re.S)
[(u'1', u'\n The full citation, including the ICC registration reference of all designations and abbreviations used in \nthis judgment are included in Annex 1. \n'), (u'2', u'\n A more detailed procedural history is set out in Annex 2 of this judgment. \nICC-01/04-02/12-271-Corr  07-04-2015  7/117  EK  A\n')]
```

Comment: _almost there_, thanks. It is just that I don't want to get what follows `8/117`...

Comment: Just add `\s*` to the lookahead in `(^\d+(?!\.).*?)(?=^\s*\d)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/n59wZV/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex which groups the data into two parts like you want, first one being the digit and second one following the paragraph data,

```
(?s)(\d+)\n +(.*?)\s*(?=\d+\n)
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?s)` --> Enables dot to match new lines which we're going to need here
- `(\d+)` --> Matches one or more digits and places them in group1
- `\n +` --> Matches the newline and `" +"` just eats any space that doesn't need to go in second capturing group
- `(.*?)` --> This group captures intended data and places in group2
- `\s*` --> This just eats any space which doesn't need to go in intended text capture
- `(?=\d+\n)` --> Look ahead point to stop capturing the intended text

**[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NhUCT5/2)**

Here is the modified version of your code,

```
import re

test_str = u"""
7. On 6 March 2013, the Appeals Chamber filed the Decision on Victim 
Participation, in which it decided that the victims “may, through their legal 

1
 The full citation, including the ICC registration reference of all designations and abbreviations used in 
this judgment are included in Annex 1. 
2
 A more detailed procedural history is set out in Annex 2 of this judgment. 
ICC-01/04-02/12-271-Corr  07-04-2015  7/117  EK  A

 8/117 
representatives, participate in the present appeal proceedings for the purpose of 
presenting their views and concerns in respect of their personal interests in the issues 
on appeal”.
3

8. On 19 March 2013, the Prosecutor filed, confidentially, ex parte, available to the 
Prosecutor and Mr Ngudjolo only, the Document in Support of the Appeal. The 
Prosecutor filed a confidential redacted version of the Document in Support of the 
Appeal on 22 March 2013, and a public redacted version of the Document in Support 
of the Appeal on 3 April 2013. In the redacted version of the Document in Support of 
the Appeal, the Prosecutor’s entire third ground of appeal was redacted. 

"""

result = re.findall(r'(?s)(\d+)\n +(.*?)\s*(?=\d+\n)', test_str)

print(result)
```

Which gives following output like you expect,

```
[('1', 'The full citation, including the ICC registration reference of all designations and abbreviations used in \nthis judgment are included in Annex 1.'), ('2', 'A more detailed procedural history is set out in Annex 2 of this judgment. \nICC-01/04-02/12-271-Corr  07-04-2015  7/117  EK  A\n\n 8/117 \nrepresentatives, participate in the present appeal proceedings for the purpose of \npresenting their views and concerns in respect of their personal interests in the issues \non appeal".')]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It is just that the reply should be `[('1', 'The full citation, including the ICC registration reference of all designations and abbreviations used in \nthis judgment are included in Anne
x 1.'), ('2', 'A more detailed procedural history is set out in Annex 2 of this judgment. \nICC-01/04-02/12-271-Corr  07-04-2015  7/117  EK  A\n\n 8/1
17 \nrepresentatives, participate in the present appeal proceedings for the purpose of \npresenting their views and concerns in respect of their perso
nal interests in the issues \non appeal".')]`. My bad for not stressing it.

Comment: @YannisP.: Actually what I did for you was indeed unusual and harder than what you actually wanted. Thank you for clarifying as to you just wanted only first two numbers and not third which was anyway not following the normal pattern. Let me update my answer to give you what you specified in your comment. It is actually much easier than my current answer.

Comment: @YannisP.: Updated my answer with new regex which gives output as you exactly expect and this was actually much easier as this is what the pattern would normally capture.

Comment: @YannisP.: I think I was able to get you exactly the output as you posted in the above comments under my answer and it left me wondering what I missed still that it didn't fulfill your question and you preferred to accepted another answer which wasn't even matching the output you mentioned and that's okay. May be some communication gap. Hope I will be able to help you better next time. Merry Christmas :)